# How to Secure Twitter Widget Iframe

Tags: javascript, twitter, widget

I am using Netsparker to security scan my site and it has flagged an issue regarding an Insecure Frame which has been generated using the Twitter Widget JS code supplied by them.

The code supplied is:

```
 <div class="twitter-timeline"> 
     <div class="twitter-timeline__heading"> 
       <h2>Twitter</h2> 
     </div>
     <a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data- 
        height="400" href="https://twitter.com/XXXXX? 
        ref_src=xxxxxxx">Tweets 
        by XXXXX
    </a> 
     <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" 
     charset="utf-8"></script> 
 </div>
```

As a remedy it suggests adding Sandbox to the IFrame tag but of course this is generated by the script above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Old post, but would be curious to know if you figured this out or not.